# Scala: Accessing subclass type information in a function

Tags: scala

I have a simple ADT:

```
trait OutputFormat
case class JsonOutputFormat() extends OutputFormat
case class AvroOutputFormat() extends OutputFormat
```

I pass an instance of one of these into a function:

```
def save(data: List[String], format: OutputFormat)
```

I want to pattern match on `format` but since it's being upcast to an `OutputFormat` I can't use a match like:

```
format match {
  case AvroOutputFormat =>
    logger.info(s"Writing Avro output to $outputPath")
    ...

  case JsonOutputFormat =>
    logger.info(s"Writing JSON output to $outputPath")
    ...
}
```

What's the best way of doing what I'm trying to do here? I could pass in a generic, but that would be a bit messy since I want to call `save` with something like:

```
formats map (f => save(data, f))
```

Using generics here would be tricky, especially with type erasure.

The alternative is to change `format` to just be a string, but then I lose the elegance of using an ADT.

Is there another elegant solution I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what pattern matching is for. What you have almost works, I've edited it below.

```
format match {
  case _: AvroOutputFormat =>
    logger.info(s"Writing Avro output to $outputPath")
    ...

  case _: JsonOutputFormat =>
    logger.info(s"Writing JSON output to $outputPath")
    ...
}
```

I've noticed that your case classes do not take parameters. If you only need a single instance of `JsonOutputFormat` and `AvroOutputFormat` each, you can make them case objects.

```
trait OutputFormat
case object JsonOutputFormat extends OutputFormat
case object AvroOutputFormat extends OutputFormat
```

In this case, you can use your original snippet, i.e. without `_:`. You may also consider making your trait `sealed`.

Comment: Ah yeah I was just told by the compiler to use `AvroOutputFormat()` etc. Glad I'm not going insane :-)

Comment: Isn't it more idiomatic to use `case AvroOutputFormat() =>` in this case? `_: AvroOutputFormat` doesn't look quite right here.

Comment: probably it is, but what is  the point of using empty case class anyway... he probably needs an `object`

Comment: @VictorMoroz it depends what you want to do. `case AvroOutputFormat(x, y, z) =>` is used to extract or match on the parameters of the case class, and `case _: AvroOutputFormat` or `case format: AvroOutputFormat` is used if you just need to match against the type. In any case, if the case class has no parameters, it should normally be substituted with a case object, in which case you can pattern match as `case AvroOutputFormat`.